# Which projection to use to map three Canadian provinces?

Tags: coordinate-system, canada

I was making a map of Alberta, Saskatchewan, and Alberta, thinking I would use a UTM projection, however, these provinces cover zones 12-16, so this likely isn't ideal. What other options are there?

Comment: Which application you are using ?

Comment: What are your objectives: to preserve area? distance? cartographic appeal?

Comment: I'm using ArcMap and trying to minimize distortion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try Albers Equal Area Conic or Lambert Conformal Conic, they would be good choices.

If you choose Lambert, adust the central meridian to 105° west, and the parallels to 50°N and 60°N.
**Canada Lambert Conformal Conic**

```
> Central Meridian -105°
> Standard Parallel 1 50°
> Standard Parallel 2 60°
> Latitude of Origin 40°
```

eg. Change the Coordinate System to Albers Equal Area and adjust central meridian.
[image: Data Frame Properities]

Comment: Thanks! How did you figure out how much to adjust the central meridian (to 105 degrees west), and the parallels adjustment?

Comment: The central meridian is approximately in the middle of the three provinces. 60 deg N is the northern border of all provinces, the southern border is actually 49 deg so you could use that instead of 50.

Comment: Thank you! If I use Albers Equal Area Conic, should I also adjust the central meridian?

Comment: Yes, I added an image to my answer.